# Warning appears when i install something using pip3

Tags: python, pip, atom-editor

I was setting up atom.So i installed **autopep8** and **flake8** using pip3. They get installed but this warning appears:

**WARNING: The script autopep8 is installed in '/home/samipkarki/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.**

**Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.**

And autopep8 and flake8 don't work in atom which i think is because of above warning.I am a beginner I searched a lot in internet but i din't not find the solution or i din't understand. I think the problem is they are not installed in PATH(I don't know what this is). So, it would be really helpful if you can tell me how i can download above things in PATH by default.

Comment: It means you have to set path in environment variables.

Comment: add /home/samipkarki/.local/bin as your environment variable path. You can google how to set a environment variable.

Comment: If the answer helped in your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @muhammed mentioned you simply need to add your `path` to your environment variables. Read here - [Add Path to Environment Variables](https://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/features/test-runners/add-path-environment-variables) on how you should do that and how the `path` system works in general.

setting this `'/home/samipkarki/.local/bin'` as your path will solve your problem.